# Python 2.7 Tkinter refresh window

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to program a GUI as a school project, it would be a program which displays game scores. I would have two windows, one in which you add points, one in which displays the score. However, I can't manage to make the two interact. Please help ! 
Here's my (long) code :

```
from tkinter import *
import pickle
##PICKLE##
gd = {"t1" : 0,"t2" : 0}

#######FUNCTIONS######
def t11():
    gd["t1"] += 10

def t12():    
    gd["t1"] += 20

def t13():    
    gd["t1"] += 30

def t14():
    gd["t2"] -= 10

def t21():   
    gd["t2"] += 10

def t22():   
    gd["t2"] += 20

def t23():
    gd["t2"] += 30

def t24():
    gd["t2"] -= 10
####UNVARIABLES####
while 1==1:
   tk = Tk()
   tk.configure(background="#a1dbcd")
   lbl = Label(tk, text="Team1",fg="red",bg="#a1dbcd",font=("Comicsans", 60))
   lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)
   lbl_ = Label(tk, text="                                                 ",bg="#a1dbcd",font=("Helvetica", 40)).grid(row=0,column=1)
   lbl2 = Label(tk, text="Team2",fg="blue",bg="#a1dbcd",font=("Helvetica", 60))
   lbl2.grid(row=0, column=2)
   master = Tk()
   #####VARIABLES#####

lbb1 = Label(tk, textvariable=gd["t1"], fg="orange",bg="#a1dbcd",fon=("jjj",70))
lbb1.grid(row=1, column=0)
lbb2 = Label(tk, textvariable=gd["t2"], fg="orange",bg="#a1dbcd",fon=("jjj",70))
lbb2.grid(row=1, column=2)
##T1##T2#

l= Label(master, text='Team1')
b= Button(master, text='ADD        10 to T1', command=t11)
b2= Button(master, text='ADD        20 to T1', command=t12)
b3= Button(master, text='ADD        30 to T1', command=t13)
b4= Button(master, text='REMOVE 10 to T1',fg="red", command=t14)
ll= Label(master, text='Team2')
bb= Button(master, text='ADD        10 to T2', command=t21)
bb2= Button(master, text='ADD        20 to T2', command=t22)
bb3= Button(master, text='ADD        30 to T2', command=t23)
bb4= Button(master, text='REMOVE 10 to T1',fg="red", command=t24)

b.grid(row=1, column=1)
b2.grid(row=2, column=1)
b3.grid(row=3, column=1)
b4.grid(row=4, column=1)
l.grid(row=0, column=1)
bb.grid(row=1, column=3)
bb2.grid(row=2, column=3)
bb3.grid(row=3, column=3)
bb4.grid(row=4, column=3)
ll.grid(row=0, column=3)

######MAINLOOPS####
tk.mainloop()
master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because the first window's mainloop is stopping the other window from running until the first window has been destroyed.
Tkinter also has to run in the main thread, so you can't thread the window's mainloops.
I would recommend just having one window and putting the score on top.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to have 2 windows ? (i'll try your technique though =D)